# Writing in the file descriptor of the child process (fd/0)

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, file-descriptors, fifo

I'm playing with file descriptors in my CentOS 7 sandbox. In doing so, I noticed an interesting situation. Suppose we've a simple PHP script:

```php
$step = 4 * 1024;

echo "php started\n";
while (!\feof(\STDIN)) {
    \fwrite(\STDOUT, 'read stdin part: '.\fread(\STDIN, $step)."\n");
}
echo "php finished\n";
```

I want to run it from the bash script as a child process in the background and pass it something in standard input, something like this:

```bsh
php read.php &
phpProcId=$(ps axw -o pid,command | grep 'read' | head -1 | sed -r 's|^\s*([0-9]+)[^0-9]+.*$|\1|g')
echo "phpProcId: $phpProcId"
echo -e "test1\ntest2" >> /proc/$phpProcId/fd/0
```

But shell output is:

```bsh
$ sh box.sh
phpProcId: 2818
$ php started
read stdin part: 
php finished
```

It looks like the bash script finishes its work before the PHP script and doesn't pass its data to the PHP subprocess in time.
How can I pass data to the php subprocess by writing to its fd/0? I do know about mkfifo and intentionally don't want to use it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP at all. This answer is about the shell.

1. > If job control is disabled […], the standard input for an asynchronous list, before any explicit redirections are performed, shall be considered to be assigned to a file that has the same properties as `/dev/null`. This shall not happen if job control is enabled. […]

   <sup>([source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_02))</sup>

   Job control is disabled by default when an `sh`-like shell executes a script.

   This means your `php read.php &` does not read from some fifo; nor does it share stdin with the whole shell script. Even if you properly identify the file it reads from (in a form of `/proc/…/fd/0` or whatever), writing to this file is like writing to `/dev/null`, not like writing to a fifo.

   If you *really* want to print to `/proc/…/fd/0` and get what you want, then you need to make it point to something that behaves like a fifo, not like `/dev/null`; therefore `mkfifo` is a sane basic choice.
2. If you think you need `phpProcId` then probably `phpProcId=$!` is better than this `phpProcId=$(ps …)` contraption you used. `$!` expands to the decimal process ID of the most recent background command executed from the current shell. It may be you don't need it though, because…
3. In Bash you can create a file descriptor that lets you print to a process. In the following example the process is `cat -n`:

   ```
   exec 3> >(cat -n)
   # ...
   echo -e "test1\ntest2" >&3
   exec 3>&-
   ```

   The writing part of this unnamed fifo is opened when we `exec`, the descriptor is closed when we `exec 3>&-` (without it: when  the shell exits). Unless some child process(es) inherit the descriptor and keep it open, `cat` will eventually exit because its stdin is no longer connected to anything, after being connected. Even if we didn't `echo`, our `cat` would exit.

   Note you may see the output from `cat` before or after your interactive shell prints a prompt after the script exits.
4. `>(…)` does not work in plain `sh`. You tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) but invoked `sh box.sh`. Use `bash` (consider a shebang) if you want `>(…)`.

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you very much!
Now I'm toying with the idea of whether there's a way to pass data to file descriptor 3, 4, 5, etc. of the child subprocess?

If the subprocess initialization looks like this: 
exec 3> >(php ...)
...I'd like to pass data to the file descriptor 3 of this subprocess (not to the standard input)
So in this case, the test string should be written to file descriptor 3 of the subprocess under consideration:
echo "test" >&3
Can I do that?

Comment: @novascriptum Let's not go [chameleon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/355310). Ask a separate question if you need.